# How can I get "395" in this sample input "General Practice, London, vol. 45 no 395 Jun 1995"?

Tags: xslt

I have this sample input

> General Practice, London, vol. 45 no **395** Jun 1995

I want to get the 395.

Here is my code. It doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<xsl:value-of select="com_ovid_content_extensions_standard_ExtensionFunctions:extractGroup(string(.),string('[Nn]o?(\d+)'),string('1'))"/>
```

Comment: If you are trying for a general solution ... does the "####" always follow " no " and have a space after?

Comment: "It doesn't work" doesn't help anyone.  What were you expecting, and what did you get?

Answer (score 1):

substring-before(substring-after('General Practice, London, vol. 45 no 395 Jun 1995',' no '),' ') yields "395" so replace that with "."

That is simple enough to use pure XSL without any extension functions.